# Mongoose populate multiple with references

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to ask if it is possible in Mongoose to have a field in schema with **multiple** references. eg. If we have a role field that references to other model specifying that role.

Like User - ref -> student/teacher.

Comment: Could you be clearer?

Comment: Do you mean [as described here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Answer (score -2):

no. mongo is no-rel db and what mongoose does is query the model you specify in the ref with the id supplied in the field data.

so, refs are basically bad practice in mongo (by default of-course).

Comment: If references in MongoDB are bad, why [does this page exist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)?

Comment: first, he meant multiple REFS in one field. that's not supported by mongoose, however can easily be done using 2 more queries - and as saying this is exactly what mongoose does.

as for the DBRefs page, it is created to help folks from rel-db's to migrate easily to MongoDB, and you can use refs, of-course, but you are missing the point of no-rel db as you can save a complete tree inside a document.

I did not say that REF's are bad only that by default it is bad practice. for some cases it is needed so you need to design your db smartly (or Schemas in the mongoose case).